# How to set up logging on dask distributed workers?

Tags: dask

After upgrading of dask distributed to version 1.15.0 my logging stopped working.

I've used `logging.config.dictConfig` to initialize python logging facilities, and previously these settings propagated to all workers. But after upgrade it doesn't work anymore.

If I do `dictConfig` right before every log call on every worker it works but it's not a proper solution.

So the question is how it initialize logging on every worker before my computation graph starts executing and do it only once per worker?

**UPDATE:**

This hack worked on a dummy example but didn't make a difference on my system:

```
def init_logging():
   # logging initializing happens here
   ...

client = distributed.Client()
client.map(lambda _: init_logging, client.ncores())
```

**UPDATE 2:**

After digging through documentation this fixed the problem:

```
client.run(init_logging)
```

So the question now is: Is this a proper way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of version 1.15.0 we now fork workers from a clean process, so changes that you make to your process prior to calling `Client()` won't affect forked workers.  For more information search for `forkserver` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods

Your solution of using `Client.run` looks good to me.  Client.run is currently (as of version 1.15.0) the best way to call a function on all currently active workers.

#### Distributed Systems

It is worth noting that here you're setting up clients forked from the same process on a single computer.  The trick you use above will not work in a distributed setting.  In case people come to this question asking about how to handle logging with Dask in a cluster context I'm adding this note.

Generally Dask does not move logs around.  Instead, it is common that whatever mechanism you used to launch Dask handles this.  Job schedulers like SGE/SLURM/Torque/PBS all do this.  Cloud systems like YARN/Mesos/Marathon/Kubernetes all do this.  The `dask-ssh` tool does this.

Comment: So this means I have to configure logging in any code chunk that is supposed to run on worker if I want to log anything, eg. to remote syslog?

Comment: Client.run method is not good enough. I had to replace all usages of Client.run() in my cluster after I found out in practice that worker processes can be terminated and restarted (not going into details). Newly started workers miss the state which was prepared by Client.run(). Therefore I use Client.scatter(global_data, broadcast=True) and in every method which is submitted to workers I check that initialization was executed on worker. I store my own "worker state" field in worker which I obtain using distributed.get_worker().
It would be nice to have distributed.worker_init(method)

Comment: Wolfgang, check out [Client.register_worker_callbacks](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html?highlight=register_worker_callbacks#distributed.Client.register_worker_callbacks).

Comment: I think distributed job logs should be separate from the worker logs. The former is about what is happening to the distributed graph processing. The latter is about what is happening to the worker. The former has context relevant to the client and the distributed job scheduler. The latter has context relevant to the cluster manager. It would be really nice if dask had a native way to capture all the logs coming from graph nodes and aggregating them into a casual trace.

Comment: Chris thank you very much for Client.register_worker_callbacks(). Unfortunately I didn't find it in dask documentation (maybe "callback" name confused me) and it is excellent for all current and future new workers initialization based on its documentation:
"The function will run immediately on all currently connected workers. It will also be run upon connection by any workers that are added in the future."