# how to make python logger setup effective in dask

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

my original script uses pool.map to run in parallel. I have logger setup in code to output to a file, and code running in different processes output logs to the same file.

now I tried to use dask for multiprocessing and found that the logger setup is not effective in other processes. my code can be simplified as below:

```
def setup_logger():
   l = logging.getLogger()
   ....
   return l

def fake_task(log: logging.Logger):
    log.info('xxxxxxxx')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ll = setup_logger()
    cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=10, threads_per_worker=1)
    client = Client(cluster)
    tasks = []
    for i in range(10):
        tasks.append(dask.delayed(fake_task)(ll))
    t = task.delayed(len)(tasks)
    t.compute()
```

but I see nothing on console or in file. I tried to move setup_logger after client = Client(cluster), it still doesn't work.

I also tried something like logger = getLogger() and then use it direcly, still no luck

one option that I have is to use yaml configuration file. but this requires code changing and another issue is that the file name contains real time information.

for example, if I run my script at 08:30 AM,the filename will be something like 0830AM.log.I am not sure how to do this in configuration. and I also prefer to setup logger in code as it's already there.

another workaround I found is to call setup_logger in each fake_task method. but this is a little bit odd as I need to pass filename around.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up logging on dask distributed workers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475239/how-to-set-up-logging-on-dask-distributed-workers)

Comment: tl;dr - dask does not manually do anything with logs - if you're using the multiprocessing backend you need to set up logging within each mapped job. writing to the same file using a global lock is a good strategy.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado when using pool.map for multiprocessing, the log setup is simple, I only need to setup logger before using pool.map.  all sub processes log to the same file, I am not sure if python logging module is using global lock internally, the logged context looks good. with the link you give, it seems logging to the same file in dask may be more complicated in essence, as dask needs to hande more complicated situations like workers on different machines. I'll do more test to find out. thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

The default logging level set by dask is higher that `info`. If you were to change your call to `log.warning`, for instance, you would see output. See the  [dask configuration](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/configuration.html) (although I don't immediately see which key configures this).

The workers set up the logging level and handler on startup, so if you need something different, you can add that to your task, call `client.run()` to change things synchronously on all workers, or set a `preload=` function for the workers. None of this may be necessary for your application.